# ¿Alguna forma de "alindar" un JSON usando JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Tengo un formulario que me devuelve un JSON con los datos variables ingresados en los input del mismo.

Debajo de este form, mediante el uso de AJAX me devuelve la respuesta esperada en formato JSON debajo del botón para enviar el formulario !

Lo que quiero saber es si existe alguna librería de JQuery o algo que me "alinde" el JSON devuelto para que no sea tan crudo y "feo" para el usuario final.

Ejemplo del JSON devuelto:

```
{"results":[{"index":"ALTC.MC_ROBERTS","hits":[{"CONTAINER_ID":"c0000000dp","LIBRARY":"ALTC","TASK":"620","REPORT":"MC_ROBERTS","ISSUE_TITTLE":"MasterCard Grupo 11","ISSUE_DATE":"2018-08-23","INDEXTEXT01T":"3044071-0-3","INDEXTEXT02T":"SCIANITTI MARTIN ALBERTO","INDEXTEXT03N":"999","LINENUM":"005","PLOG":"457031","CRC":"1690321124"},{"CONTAINER_ID":"c0000000dp","LIBRARY":"ALTC","TASK":"620","REPORT":"MC_ROBERTS","ISSUE_TITTLE":"MasterCard Grupo 11","ISSUE_DATE":"2018-08-23","INDEXTEXT01T":"3044071-0-3","INDEXTEXT02T":"SCIANITTI MARTIN ALBERTO","INDEXTEXT03N":"999","LINENUM":"005","PLOG":"457032","CRC":"768121840"},{"CONTAINER_ID":"c0000000dp","LIBRARY":"ALTC","TASK":"620","REPORT":"MC_ROBERTS","ISSUE_TITTLE":"MasterCard Grupo 11","ISSUE_DATE":"2018-08-23","INDEXTEXT01T":"3044071-0-3","INDEXTEXT02T":"SCIANITTI MARTIN ALBERTO","INDEXTEXT03N":"999","LINENUM":"005","PLOG":"457033","CRC":"448363951"},{"CONTAINER_ID":"c0000000dp","LIBRARY":"ALTC","TASK":"620","REPORT":"MC_ROBERTS","ISSUE_TITTLE":"MasterCard Grupo 11","ISSUE_DATE":"2018-08-23","INDEXTEXT01T":"3044071-0-3","INDEXTEXT02T":"SCIANITTI MARTIN ALBERTO","INDEXTEXT03N":"999","LINENUM":"005","PLOG":"457034","CRC":"3900609116"},{"CONTAINER_ID":"c0000000dp","LIBRARY":"ALTC","TASK":"620","REPORT":"MC_ROBERTS","ISSUE_TITTLE":"MasterCard Grupo 11","ISSUE_DATE":"2018-08-23","INDEXTEXT01T":"3044071-0-3","INDEXTEXT02T":"SCIANITTI MARTIN ALBERTO","INDEXTEXT03N":"999","LINENUM":"005","PLOG":"457031","CRC":"1690321124"}
```

Esto se ve medio feo para usuario! Hay alguna forma de hacerlo más amigable mediante alguna librería de JQUERY o alguna librería externa ??

Muchas gracias !

Comment: Si se trata de un archivo .json lo puedes abrir en Firefox que te lo devuelve formateado

Comment: Claro, lo que pasa es que mi JSON lo estoy devolviendo en una etiqueta <span> dentro de mi HTML ... se ve todo feucho ... hay alguna forma de formatearlo para que quede lindo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí lo tienes. Es importante que el JSON sea válido.

```js
let json = {"results":[{"index":"ALTC.MC_ROBERTS","hits":[{"CONTAINER_ID":"c0000000dp","LIBRARY":"ALTC","TASK":"620","REPORT":"MC_ROBERTS","ISSUE_TITTLE":"MasterCard Grupo 11","ISSUE_DATE":"2018-08-23","INDEXTEXT01T":"3044071-0-3","INDEXTEXT02T":"SCIANITTI MARTIN ALBERTO","INDEXTEXT03N":"999","LINENUM":"005","PLOG":"457031","CRC":"1690321124"},{"CONTAINER_ID":"c0000000dp","LIBRARY":"ALTC","TASK":"620","REPORT":"MC_ROBERTS","ISSUE_TITTLE":"MasterCard Grupo 11","ISSUE_DATE":"2018-08-23","INDEXTEXT01T":"3044071-0-3","INDEXTEXT02T":"SCIANITTI MARTIN ALBERTO","INDEXTEXT03N":"999","LINENUM":"005","PLOG":"457032","CRC":"768121840"}]}]}

test.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json,null,4);// indentación a 4 espacios
```

```html
<pre id="test"></pre>
```